# dynamically memory allocation of a matrix in an array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, structure, allocation

I would like to make an array of structure with dynamic allocation of memory for the structure and the two matrix

```
typedef struct {
    int **cont;
    double **doubmat;
} libra;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    libra *arra = calloc(Nfr,sizeof(libra));

    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        arra[i].doubmat = calloc(Nmol, sizeof (libra));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Nmol; j++) arra[i].doubmat[j] = calloc(Nmol, sizeof (libra));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        arra[i].cont = calloc(Nmol, sizeof (libra));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Nmol; j++) arra[i].cont[j] = calloc(Nmol, sizeof (libra));
    }
    }
```

but i have some trouble with memory, the numbers during the calculation depends on the number of structure in the array. I think that I'm making some mistake with the allocation.

Anyone have some tips ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show us a complete program.  For example what is `Nfr`?  And tell us the exact, specific error you got.

Comment: Nfr is given in input, **Nfr = atoi(argv[5]);** . I suppose that there is a allocation error because the content of **arra[i].doubmat[j][k]** depends on Nfr. The program compile without any problem and there aren't any segmentation fault message at the end. If Nfr is 1 the numbers inside **arra[i].doubmat[j][k]** are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified incorrect sizeof(type) to allocate memory for matrices.
You need to do something like that:

```
typedef struct {
    int **cont;
    double **doubmat;
} libra;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    libra *arra = calloc(Nframe,sizeof(libra));

    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        arra[i].doubmat = calloc(Nmol, sizeof(*arra[i].doubmat));
        for (j = 0; j < Nmol; j++)
            arra[i].doubmat[j] = calloc(Nmol, sizeof(**arra[i].doubmat));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Nfr; i++) {
        arra[i].cont = calloc(Nmol, sizeof(*arra[i].cont));
        for (j = 0; j < Nmol; j++)
            arra[i].cont[j] = calloc(Nmol, sizeof(**arra[i].cont));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that NFrame is declared, I am going to show the allocation for an array of consisting of `Nframe` structs, each of which contains a `Nrows`x`Ncols` `doubmat`:

```
typedef struct {
    int **cont;
    double **doubmat;
} libra;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, j, Nrows = ..., Ncols = ...;
    libra *arra = calloc(Nframe, sizeof(libra));

    for (i = 0; i < Nframe; i++) {
        arra[i].doubmat = calloc(Nrows, sizeof(double*));
        if (arra[i].doubmat == NULL)
            return;
        for (j = 0; j < Nmol; j++){
            arra[i].doubmat[j] = calloc(Ncols, sizeof(double));
            if (arra[i].doubmat[j] == NULL)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```